# Node.js - Is it safe to use `fork()` with node-ffi or add-on?

Tags: node.js, linux, node.js-addon, node-ffi

I'm writing some script to trace a child process. However, I don't want to write C code, so I'm considering to use the node-ffi module to handle the stuff. But I have to fork a new process and call execve() then to run the child. Is that safe?

By `fork()` I mean the POSIX fork, not `child_process.fork()`. I wonder if the child process and the parent process share the same file descriptors, will there be any problem (for example, parent and child read the same required . js file)?

Comment: What do you mean by safe? There do not appear to be any open issues in node-ffi's github repo related to fork, child_process, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is OK. `fork()` will only fork the current thread, not the entire process so other Node.js routines will not be forked. But remember to use `_exit(2)` syscall to exit. Don't use `exit(3)` proviede by glibc as it may cause SIGSEGV.